# Laravel 9 Getting error Upload Form Submit to Database and give an error message

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-9

i have a problem upload my form to database using post method in route::middleware and get an error like this
***The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.***

i dont know where to check it again.please help me.i already do solution from another post in here but it still not solve.

web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/dashboard','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FrontendController@index');

Route::get('categories','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@index');
Route::get('add-category','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@add');
Route::get('insert-category','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@insert'); });
```

CategoryController.php

```
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $category = new Category();
    if($request->hasFile('image')->isValid())
    // {
    //     $file = $request->file('image');
    //     $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    //     $filename = time().'.'.$ext;
    //     $file->move('assets/uploads/category',$filename);
    //     $category->image = $filename;

    // }


    $category->name = $request->input('name');
    $category->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $category->description = $request->input('description');
    $category->status = $request->input('status') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
    $category->popular = $request->input('popular') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
    $category->meta_title = $request->input('meta_title');
    $category->meta_keywords = $request->input('meta_keywords');
    $category->meta_descrip = $request->input('meta_description');
    $category->save();
    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('status',"Category Added Succesfully");
}
```

this is Model Category.php

```
class Category extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'categories';
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'slug',
    'description',
    'status',
    'popular',
    'image',
    'meta_title',
    'meta_descrip',
    'meta_keywords',
];}
```

and this is my form add.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ url('insert-category') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Slug</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="slug">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Status</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="status">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Popular</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="popular">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Meta_title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="meta_title">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Meta_Keyword</label>
                    <textarea name="meta_keywords" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                    <label for="">Meta_Description</label>
                    <textarea name="meta_description" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your route is a `GET` route (`Route::get`)while your form method is `POST`. Both should be the same; ideally POST for store/insert requests (`Route::post('in..)`).

Comment: i still get an error when i change to post route like this. The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: dump composer autoload `composer du` and see if it fixes

Comment: yeahh thank you sir..it works..i also do with php artisan route:cache and php artisan optimize

Comment: Route cache and php artisan optimize are deployment commands. Typically you would avoid running those during development. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert-category should be a POST route instead of a GET i-e

```
Route::post('insert-category','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@insert');
```

Comment: You have defined insert-category route as a get route which means you can only use the get method to access it but in your form you are using POST .

Comment: yeah i already change it but still error. The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: try to run php artisan route:cache and php artisan optimize

Answer (score 0):

use code :

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FrontendController@index');
    Route::get('categories','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@index');
    Route::get('add-category','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@add');
    Route::post('insert-category','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController@insert'); 
});
```

I also suggest using this structured routing :

use namespace :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController;
```

and routing :

```
Route::post('insert-category', [CategoryController::class, 'insert'])
    ->name('insert-category');
```